# EF5 CodeFirst + Relationships between non-key columns

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

In have two classes;

```
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual BinCard BinCard { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class BinCard
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public double Qty { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Item> Item { get; set; }
}
```

The **BinCard.Id** is the **PK** and **auto increments**.

I want the relationship between two tables using **Item.Id** and **BinCard.ItemId** using**FluentAPI**.

Please help me to create this relationship correctly.

Comment: **modelBuilder.Entity<BinCard>()                        .HasRequired(d => d.Item).WithMany().HasForeignKey(s => s.ItemId);**
Then, in the FK **BinCard** table is ok. But in the **Item** table, it refers the **Id** (Auto Increment column). Not the **ItemId** column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all replies. This is the solution for my question.

```
public class BinCard
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public double Qty { get; set; }

    public virtual Drug Drug { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<BinCard> BinCard { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Drug>()
            .HasRequired(s => s.Stock)
            .WithRequiredPrincipal(s => s.Drug);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

EF does not support non-PK principal Ids because it doesn't support unique keys other than PKs yet. To make this work you will have to create relationship based on `BinCard.Id` and `BinCardId` to `Item` entity - btw. it looks like the correct way to build relationship in your model. Your current model looks really strange.